# How to use the reset method to clear the event?

Tags: javascript

I have a mouseover event that changes the color of 4 elements individually and to also show the text attach to it but I can't get the (overflow: hidden) property to change and also after each event the elements don't reset back to the original format they stay the same. I tried to use the reset() but was unsuccessful.

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tab green">
            <i class="fas fa-1x fa-home"></i>
            <p>Home</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tab red">
            <i class="fas fa-1x  fa-heart"></i>
            <p>Likes</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tab grey">
            <i class="fas fa-1x  fa-search"></i>
            <p>Search</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tab blue">
            <i class="fas fa-1x  fa-user"></i>
            <p>User</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

css

```
.container {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
    position: relative;
    width: 468px;
    max-width: 480px;
    min-height: 480px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.tab  {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tab p {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.tab:hover, .p:hover {

  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;

}
```

javascript

```
let tab = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
let p = document.querySelectorAll('.p');
let background = document.querySelector('body');
let green = document.querySelector('.green');
let red = document.querySelector('.red');
let grey = document.querySelector('.grey');
let blue = document.querySelector('.blue');
let container = document.querySelector('.container');



red.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
     red.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
     background.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
     tab.p.style.overflow = 'visible'; // tried to used this to get text to show

});


green.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    green.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    background.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
});



grey.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    grey.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
    background.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
});

blue.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    blue.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    background.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
});
```

Comment: `window.setTimeout('mouseout', 3000, blue.style.backgroundColor = 'blue')` doesn’t make sense in a few ways. Take a look at [the MDN documentation for `setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

Comment: Thanks, It was something I was trying out and just forgot to delete it.

Comment: Did you assign anything to `tab.p` before? In general, a child element can’t be accessed by using its name as a property name – you could try `tab.querySelector('p')`. Make sure to check your console for errors as a debugging tool, and include them in the question if you need help resolving them.

Comment: Thank you so much. Very very helpful and informative that i will definitely remember. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

- First, if you look in your console, you'll probably see an error on this line:

  `tab.p.style.overflow = 'visible';`

  `p` is not a property of `tab`. `tab` is a node list, so you can't access the `p` elements within the `tab` class that way. Instead, try:

  `document.querySelectorAll('.tab p')`
- Secondly, as mentioned above, `querySelectorAll` returns a node list. This is like an array. So before you can modify any CSS on a node, you have to select **which** node in the node list you want to modify. For example:

  `document.querySelectorAll('.tab p')[0]`
- Finally, you need to attach an event handler to the `mouseout` event to revert the styles after the user moves their mouse out of the element.

Below is a complete example for red only. Hover your cursor in the middle of your shadow box and you should see the desired effect. Note that I made the box height smaller just for this demonstration. Also, I'm not sure if the text is aligned exactly as you want it, but since it wasn't specified in your question I didn't address that.

```js
let tab = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
let p = document.querySelectorAll('.p');
let background = document.querySelector('body');
let red = document.querySelector('.red');

red.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  red.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  background.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  document.querySelectorAll('.tab p')[0].style.overflow = 'visible';
});

red.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
  red.style.backgroundColor = "";
  background.style.backgroundColor = "";
  document.querySelectorAll('.tab p')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';
})
```

```css
.container {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.tab {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab p {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.tab:hover,
.p:hover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab red">
    <i class="fas fa-1x  fa-heart"></i>
    <p>Likes</p>
  </div>
</div>
```